# How to create dynamic query tags using SnowflakeOperator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

Using the snowflake operator, I would like to dynamically set the query tag to show the dag_id, task_id, and run_id.
This would allow easy troubleshooting in Snowflake Query History.

I'm able to set a static query tag using the session_parameters attribute of the snowflake operator.

```
with DAG(
    "test_querytags",
    description="Refreshes entities shared by all projects",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule='15 8 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    default_view="graph",
    tags=["admin","common","calendar","daily"],
) as dag:      

    t_Load_Data = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id="SF__Load_Data",
        sql="CALL SANDBOX_OR.RAW.LOAD_CITY_2_P('SANDBOX_OR')",
        session_parameters={"QUERY_TAG": "test query tag"
        )
```

However, I can't manage to find a way to use the dag_id, run_id, or task_id to generate my query tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it by using the Jinja template

for example to access dag_id you can use `"{{dag.dag_id}}"`

```
with DAG(
    "test_querytags",
    description="Refreshes entities shared by all projects",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule='15 8 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    default_view="graph",
    tags=["admin","common","calendar","daily"],
) as dag:      

    t_Load_Data = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id="SF__Load_Data",
        sql="CALL SANDBOX_OR.RAW.LOAD_CITY_2_P('SANDBOX_OR')",
        session_parameters={"QUERY_TAG": "{{dag.dag_id}}"
        )
```

check other templated variables here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html